# Minimax function not returning correct results

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have made a tic tac toe discord bot to play tic tac toe with(against) me. The algorithm works pretty good, but it almost never seems to block me or take wins, even when I try to make it. I have tried lots of debugging, and I really don't think that anything is bugged, I just think my logic is slightly off. Here's my MiniMax function.

```
function MINIMAX(Board, Depth, MaximizingScore, CTS) {
        var value = 0;
        var score = EvaluateBoard(Board);
        if (score == 10) {
           return score; 
        }

            // If Minimizer has won the game  
            // return his/her evaluated score 
            if (score == -10) {
            return score; 
        }
        if(IsTerminalState(Board) && CTS) {
        return 0;
        }

        var PossibleMoves = FindPossibleMoves(Board);
        if(MaximizingScore) {
        //When AI is calculated
        var BestVal = -1000;
        for(var i = 0; i < PossibleMoves.length; i++) {
            var Ii = PossibleMoves[i];
            Board[Ii] = "X";
            BestVal = Math.max(BestVal, MINIMAX(Board, Depth + 1, !MaximizingScore, true));
            Board[Ii] = "N"
        }
        return BestVal;
        } else {
        //When Player is calculated
        var BestVal = 1000;
        for(var i = 0; i < PossibleMoves.length; i++) {
            var Ii = PossibleMoves[i];
            Board[Ii] = "O";
            BestVal = Math.min(BestVal, MINIMAX(Board, Depth + 1, !MaximizingScore, true));
            Board[Ii] = "N"
        }
        return BestVal;
        }
}
```

And I use a similar function to find the best possible move. Here it is:

```
function FindBestMove(Board) {
        var bestVal = -1000;
        var bestMove = 0;
        var PossibleMoves = FindPossibleMoves(Board);
        for(var i = 0; i < PossibleMoves.length; i++) {
        var Ii = PossibleMoves[i];
        Board[Ii] = "X";
        moveVal = MINIMAX(Board, 0, false, false);
        console.log(moveVal);
        Board[Ii] = "N"
        if(moveVal > bestVal) {
            bestMove = Ii;
            bestVal = moveVal;
        }
        }
        return bestMove;
    }
```

I have looked on multiple websites, and they all seem to use the same algorithm. I don't know what's wrong with my logic, but I have done a little debugging and found that the Minimax almost always returns -10. I think the problem is since it sends -10 for every value, it just picks the first space it could put something in (Because it can't set the maximum higher due to the fact that -10 !> -10.)  but what I need a little help with is why it thinks that blocking or winning is worth the same as loosing. Here's a screenshot of the values it returns.

[image]

It does occasionally return 0, but not very often.

I'm not exactly looking for code, I would just like to see what's wrong with my algorithm. Sorry if this post is kind of bad, I just am not sure exactly what's wrong. I've been debugging for so long that I just don't know what else to do. Thanks =)

Oh, and here's a code snippet of problems I'm experiencing. If you put this AI in almost any situation like this we get the same result.

```js
console.log(FindBestMove(["O", "X", "N", "X", "X", "O", "N", "O", "X"]));//2 would be the 3nd element in the array. This would not be ideal because we would want to block X in this case, so this results in a loose.
function calculateWinX(gamearr) {
            //HORIZONTAL
            if(gamearr[0]=="X" && gamearr[1]=="X" && gamearr[2]=="X") {return true}
            if(gamearr[3]=="X" && gamearr[4]=="X" && gamearr[5]=="X") {return true}
            if(gamearr[6]=="X" && gamearr[7]=="X" && gamearr[8]=="X") {return true}
            
            //VERTICAL
            if(gamearr[2]=="X" && gamearr[5]=="X" && gamearr[8]=="X") {return true}
            if(gamearr[1]=="X" && gamearr[4]=="X" && gamearr[7]=="X") {return true}
            if(gamearr[0]=="X" && gamearr[3]=="X" && gamearr[6]=="X") {return true}
            
            //DIAGONAL
            if(gamearr[0]=="X" && gamearr[4]=="X" && gamearr[8]=="X") {return true}
            if(gamearr[6]=="X" && gamearr[4]=="X" && gamearr[2]=="X") {return true}
            return false;
        }
        function calculateWinO(gamearr) {
            //HORIZONTAL
            if(gamearr[0]=="O" && gamearr[1]=="O" && gamearr[2]=="O") {return true}
            if(gamearr[3]=="O" && gamearr[4]=="O" && gamearr[5]=="O") {return true}
            if(gamearr[6]=="O" && gamearr[7]=="O" && gamearr[8]=="O") {return true}
            
            //VERTICAL
            if(gamearr[2]=="O" && gamearr[5]=="O" && gamearr[8]=="O") {return true}
            if(gamearr[1]=="O" && gamearr[4]=="O" && gamearr[7]=="O") {return true}
            if(gamearr[0]=="O" && gamearr[3]=="O" && gamearr[6]=="O") {return true}
            
            //DIAGONAL
            if(gamearr[0]=="O" && gamearr[4]=="O" && gamearr[8]=="O") {return true}
            if(gamearr[6]=="O" && gamearr[4]=="O" && gamearr[2]=="O") {return true}
            return false;
        }
    function IsTerminalState(gamearr) {
        return !gamearr.includes("N");
    }
    function FindPossibleMoves(gamearr) {
        var PossibleMoves = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(gamearr[i]==="N") {
                PossibleMoves.push(i);
            }
        }
        return PossibleMoves;
    }
    function EvaluateBoard(gamearr) {
        if(calculateWinO(gamearr)) {
        return 10;
        }
        if(calculateWinX(gamearr)) {
        return -10;
        }
    }
        function MINIMAX(Board, Depth, MaximizingScore, CTS) {
        var value = 0;
        var score = EvaluateBoard(Board);
        if (score == 10) {
           return score; 
        }

            // If Minimizer has won the game  
            // return his/her evaluated score 
            if (score == -10) {
            return score; 
        }
        if(IsTerminalState(Board) && CTS) {
        return 0;
        }

        var PossibleMoves = FindPossibleMoves(Board);
        if(MaximizingScore) {
        //When AI is calculated
        var BestVal = -1000;
        for(var i = 0; i < PossibleMoves.length; i++) {
            var Ii = PossibleMoves[i];
            Board[Ii] = "X";
            BestVal = Math.max(BestVal, MINIMAX(Board, Depth + 1, !MaximizingScore, true));
            Board[Ii] = "N"
        }
        return BestVal;
        } else {
        //When Player is calculated
        var BestVal = 1000;
        for(var i = 0; i < PossibleMoves.length; i++) {
            var Ii = PossibleMoves[i];
            Board[Ii] = "O";
            BestVal = Math.min(BestVal, MINIMAX(Board, Depth + 1, !MaximizingScore, true));
            Board[Ii] = "N"
        }
        return BestVal;
        }
        }
    function FindBestMove(Board) {
        var bestVal = -1000;
        var bestMove = 0;
        var PossibleMoves = FindPossibleMoves(Board);
        for(var i = 0; i < PossibleMoves.length; i++) {
        var Ii = PossibleMoves[i];
        Board[Ii] = "X";
        moveVal = MINIMAX(Board, 0, false, false);
        console.log(moveVal);
        Board[Ii] = "N"
        if(moveVal > bestVal) {
            bestMove = Ii;
            bestVal = moveVal;
        }
        }
        return bestMove;
    }
```

Comment: Please make a runnable example, otherwise it's hard to help you find the flaw in your logic

Comment: @IvanD It's a discord bot, I don't know how to make a runnable example due to the fact that it just sends the messages and things. I'll try to make an example, but it might take a bit =)

Comment: Mock the outputs into `console.log`s for example :)

Comment: @IvanD Done with the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple, but effective way for calculating the next best move for the bot to make:

```js
const checkBlank = (vals) => {
  const v = (vals.filter(val => !val));
  
  if (v.length !== 0) {
    return vals.indexOf(v[0]);
  }
  
  return v;
}


const winningConditions = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
];


const board = [
  '', 'O', '',
  '', 'X', '',
  'X', '', '',
];


const previousMove = 6;
const botCharacter = 'O';
const playerCharacter = 'X';


function bestNextMove() {
  let randomBlank = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < winningConditions.length; i++) {
    const winningCondition = winningConditions[i];
    
    if (! winningCondition.includes(previousMove)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    let counter = 0;
    
    const [firstPos, secondPos, thirdPos] = winningCondition;
    
    const boardPos1 = board[firstPos], 
          boardPos2 = board[secondPos], 
          boardPos3 = board[thirdPos];
    
    const blankCheck = checkBlank([boardPos1, boardPos2, boardPos3]);
    
    randomBlank = blankCheck !== false ? winningCondition[blankCheck] : randomBlank;
    
    const str = boardPos1 + boardPos2 + boardPos3;
    
    if (str === playerCharacter + playerCharacter && blankCheck !== false) {
      return randomBlank;
    }
  }
  
  return randomBlank;
}

console.log(bestNextMove());
```

#### Explanation

I'm checking to see if a winning condition exists where the player can win in the next turn, then returning the proper coordinates needed to block that winning move.

`bestNextMove` will also return a valid starting move if no moves have been made yet, or there is not a condition where the player would win.

My example contains an example board wherein 3 moves have already been made and it is now on the bot to determine the next best move based on the given criteria

Comment: Wow! This works very well. The only reason I didn't do something like this is because my bot(If the logic works) will try to set up a winning situation because it looks at all the possible moves, not just the current board. This is something that would defiantly work, I just wanted the AI to not place "random" moves when there's not a situation it can win in.

Comment: @Glitch752 you could always use this first, and have it return false at the end if you can make a smarter move based on logic outside of protecting against a loss

Comment: Yes, indeed. I will try to do that. This, of course, could happen to mess up something the bot is trying to do, but It would defiantly work better than my current AI ;)

Comment: @Glitch752 - if the answer helps you, make sure to upvote and if it really helped, accept :) I did enjoy this little exercise, definitely got my creative flowing